# Spring Transactional not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, dao, transactional

I'v setup a Spring/Hibernate backend based on following example using Spring 4.1 and Hibernate 4.3.6:

http://www.sivalabs.in/2011/02/springhibernate-application-with-zero.html

I basically got everything working so far, but there is one little configuration problem I can't overcome: If I try to save an Entity I get the following StackTrace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.checkWriteOperationAllowed(HibernateTemplate.java:1135)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:620)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:617)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:340)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:308)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:617)
at com.test.database.dao.UserSecurityQuestionDAOImpl.save(UserSecurityQuestionDAOImpl.java:40)
at com.test.database.service.UserSecurityQuestionService.save(UserSecurityQuestionService.java:20)
at com.test.database.UserSecurityQuestionTest.basicCreationAndRetrievalTest(UserSecurityQuestionTest.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

My transactional directive is placed in the Service Bean and looks like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserSecurityQuestionService implements UserSecurityQuestionDAO{

    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityQuestionDAO userSecurityQuerstionDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public void save(UserSecurityQuestion userSecurityQuestion) {
        userSecurityQuerstionDAO.save(userSecurityQuestion);        
    }
```

This is my DAO Implementation of the save Method:

```
@Repository
public class UserSecurityQuestionDAOImpl implements UserSecurityQuestionDAO {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager; 

    public void save(UserSecurityQuestion userSecurityQuestion) {
        Session session = transactionManager.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(userSecurityQuestion);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

Selecting from the Database works fine, but Inserts/Updates are refused throwing above Error Message. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

UserSecurityQuestionDAOImpl:

```
public class UserSecurityQuestionDAOImpl implements UserSecurityQuestionDAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void save(UserSecurityQuestion userSecurityQuestion) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(userSecurityQuestion);
    }
```

UserSecurityQuestionDAO / UserSecurityQuestionService - Interfaces:

```
public interface UserSecurityQuestionService {
    public void save(UserSecurityQuestion userSecurityQuestion);    
    public UserSecurityQuestion findById(Short id); 
    public List<UserSecurityQuestion> findAll();    
    public void delete(UserSecurityQuestion userSecurityQuestion);  
    public void deleteById(Short... id);    
}
```

Service Implementation:

```
@Service
public class UserSecurityQuestionServiceImpl implements UserSecurityQuestionService {

    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityQuestionDAO userSecurityQuestionDAO;    

    @Transactional
    public void save(UserSecurityQuestion userSecurityQuestion) {
        userSecurityQuestionDAO.save(userSecurityQuestion);     
    }
```

Unit test code Used for Testing:

```
public class UserSecurityQuestionTest {

    private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();      
    private UserSecurityQuestionService usqService;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        //Setup App Context
        ctx.scan("com.test.database");
        ctx.refresh();

        //Initilize Service Bean
        usqService = ctx.getBean("userSecurityQuestionService",UserSecurityQuestionServiceImpl.class);
    }
```

New Problem: If I add `@Autowired` to the `private UserSecurityQuestionService usqService;` and omit the Setup-Part, I will get a Null pointer Exception. If I leave the code as it is, I get `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userSecurityQuestionService' is defined`

Comment: You don't have transactions. IN your config add `<tx:annotation-driven />` or `@EnableTransactionManagement`. Also you shouldn't be using `HibernaetTemplate` but rather `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession` (this is the recommendation since Hibernate 3.0.1 actually!).

Comment: Okay, I just noticed that the example I used as template wasn't that new. Check my updated post, ist it properly configured now?

Comment: No because you are still using manual tx management and have actually made it worse by injecting the transaction manager. Inject the `SessionFactory` and instead of `openSession` use `getCurrentSession` and remove all the transactional stuff and session closing. Your method should be 2 lines.

Comment: Alright I think I almost got it now (see update). Just somehow the AUtowiring doesent seem to work properly in the unit test.

Comment: Don't roll your own, use the spring test support instead. Also the bean will be named after the classname with a lowercase first letter so `UserSecurityQuestionServiceImpl` becomes `userSecurityQuestionServiceImpl` and you should use the interface instead of the concrete class (the latter won't work due to a dynamic proxy being created to apply transactions).

Comment: Alright I got it working now! Just forgot to add the bean name in the @Service Annotation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that both you service class and your dao implements same interface, and that you autowire the dao in service by its class.

I assume your service is also autowired by its class in your controller. It would be better to have separate interfaces for service and dao to allow autowiring by type using an interface. That way, Spring will use a JDK proxy (the default) to implement the transactional proxy around your service bean.

The alternative would be to use `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true/>`", but you then need to have CGLIB in your path.

Comment: So if I get your proposal right, I should have an Interface called "UserSecurityQuestionService" that is implemented in my "UserSecurityQuestionServiceImpl"-Class and another one called "UserSecurityQuestionDAO" implemented by "UserSecurityQuestionDAOImpl". Where should I place which annotations now?

Comment: You can leave the annotations in the implementation class. From Spring Framework Reference Manual (Transaction chapter) : *Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods of concrete classes) with the @Transactional annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces.*

Comment: Okay, now I got the following error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'userSecurityQuestionService' must be of type [com.test.database.service.UserSecurityQuestionService], but was actually of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30]
This must be the Proxy-Stuff you have been talking about before. I updated my above post so you can see the current setup. Now using UserSecurityQuestionDAO instead of UserSecurityQuestionDAOImpl. Am I doing this right?